# Are American Paskesz Products Yoshon?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, yashan-chadash, dagan-five-grains

Are American Paskesz grain products, such as [Mini Trios Bites](http://paskesz.com/product/01315-mini-trios-bites-vanilla/), *[yoshon](https://yoshon.com/what-is-yoshon/)* year round?  Is there a way to determine from, e.g., a package code if/when they are *yoshon*?  (Paskesz cookies under Rav Westheim of Manchester are [apparently yoshon](https://yoshon.com/product/paskesz-cookies-under-rav-westheim/?highlight=paskesz), however, the American product appears to only be certified by a Rabbi Gruber of Monsey, NY with no indication of yoshon status [other than that it appears to also be marked for sale in Israel]).

Comment: Have you tried to contact them?

Comment: @Kazibácsi I'm waiting to hear back.